# connection between python and sql server database

Tags: python, database

```py
def create(conn):
    try:
        print(f"Full Name: {FullName}")
        print(f"Reference No: {ReferenceNumber}")
        print(f"Phone: {Phone}")
        print(f"Age: {Age}")
        print(f"Address {Address}")
        print(f"Treatment Type: {TreatmentType}")
        print(f"Check In Date: {CheckInDate}")
        print(f"Appointment Date: {AppointmentDate}")
        print(f"Payment Method: {PaymentMethod}")
        print(f" Total Paid: {TotalPaid}")
        print(f"Gender: {Gender}")
        # Print other input values...

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO PatientInfo(FullName, ReferenceNumber, Phone, Age, Address, TreatmentType, CheckInDate, AppointmentDate, PaymentMethod, TotalPaid, Gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);',
            (
                FullName.get(),
                ReferenceNumber.get(),
                Phone.get(),
                Age.get(),
                Address.get(),
                TreatmentType.get(),
                CheckInDate.get(),
                AppointmentDate.get(),
                PaymentMethod.get(),
                TotalPaid.get(),
                Gender.get(),
                # Add similar lines for other input values...
            )
        )
        conn.commit()
        print("Data successfully inserted.")
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        # Handle database errors here
        print(f"Database error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle other exceptions here
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# Usage example:
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    'Server=DESKTOP-6CDVKVT\\SQLEXPRESS;'
    'Database=Dhoolacade;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

# Call the create() function with the established connection
create(conn)

# Close the connection when done
conn.close()
```

first of all the connection is successful and i tried to double check what information am i submiting and print my variables in order to the values i that i am storing in my table and here what i get in the terminal

output:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dashboard\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\User\Desktop\LoginForm\login.py 
Full Name: PY_VAR0
Reference No: PY_VAR1
Phone: PY_VAR2
Age: PY_VAR3
Address PY_VAR4
Treatment Type: PY_VAR5
Check In Date: PY_VAR6
Appointment Date: PY_VAR7
Payment Method: PY_VAR8
Total Paid: PY_VAR9
Gender: PY_VAR10
Data successfully inserted.
```

Additionally when i check my database Table it actually adds new rows with no data inside or simply it adds blank rows

Comment: Print the result of `.get()` on those variables to see what you are actually inserting.

Comment: Do `print(f"Full Name: {FullName.get()}")` instead of `print(f"Full Name: {FullName}")`.  You are inserting the return value of `Fullname.get()`, not `Fullname`. (This applies to all of the variables).

Comment: i have tried it but it shows no output

Comment: If `Fullname.get()` is returning `None` (or an empty string) then the problem is probably in the code where it is defined (is it a tkinter window?)

Comment: yes this is the whole code by the way i am just new to coding :

Comment: i fixed the problem bro thanks for helping. I was writing this FullName = StringVar() instead of writing this FullName = tk.StringVar(win) . Thanks appreciate your help